# Porque recibo este error?? Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, poo, pdo

Mi idea es hacer una insercion usando PDO pero me da un error en la linea donde dice "contraseña" => $contraseña y ni siquiera me pasa de este modelo y ademas me da un error en la linea del $rol='user' ¿porque?

```
public function save(){

    $sql=$this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES(:doc_ident, :nombre, :apellidos, :fecha_nac, :correo, :sexo, :pais, :rol, :contraseña);");   
    $doc_ident=$this->getDoc_ident();

    $nombre= $this->getNombre();
    $apellidos=$this->getApellidos();
    $fecha_nac=$this->getFecha_nac();
    $correo=$this->getCorreo();
    $sexo= $this->getSexo();                  
    $pais= $this->getPais();
    $rol='user';
    $contraseña=$this->getContraseña();


    $sql->execute([
        "doc_ident" => $doc_ident,
        "nombre" => $nombre,
        "apellidos" => $apellidos,
        "fecha_nac" => $fecha_nac,
        "correo" => $correo,
        "sexo" => $sexo,
        "pais" => $pais,
        "rol" => $rol,
        "contraseña" => $contraseña
    ]);


$result=false;
if($sql){
  $result=true;  
}

return $result;
}
```

Comment: Prueba a no usar ñs en los nombres de variables. Suelen dar problemas.

Comment: intenta añadir las comillas simples en el insert para los campos que son texto.

Comment: La `ñ` y los acentos dan problemas si no controlas bien la codificación de tu entorno PHP-HTML-BASE DE DATOS. Más de una vez se han visto aquí errores debido a eso. Si puedes, evita el uso de `ñ` o caracteres acentuados, tanto en los nombres de tablas/columnas (base de datos), como en los nombres de variables. Si esto no es posible, entonces debes controlar bien la codificación, usando preferiblemente UTF-8 a nivel global.